# Populating a select box on my razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have the following class:

```
public class Note : TableServiceEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string NoteDetailsJSON { get; set; }
}
```

It contains short descriptions that I would like to put into a select list in my view.

I get the data from the table like this.

```
Notes = noteTable.GetAll()
```

I have my viewmodel look like this:

```
 public IEnumerable<Note> Notes { get; set; }
```

However when I try to populate my select box I get only the following:

```
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(
                        x => x.Level,
                        new SelectList(Model.Notes, "Description", "Description"),
                        new { style = "display: inline;" }
                    )

                        <select id="Level" name="Level" style="display: inline;"><option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>
<option value=""></option>

</select>
```

Some help on how to populate the select box would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get what your question or problem is. Most probably `noteTable.GetAll()` simply returns empty objects.

So assuming you have the following view model which contains a list of notes:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Level { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

and your controller action properly populates this model:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Notes = noteTable.GetAll().ToList() // make sure that this returns some data
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

obviously the best way to ensure that your problem is not in the data source is to initially hardcode some data:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var model = new MyViewModel
    {
        Notes = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(x => new Note
        {
            Description = "note description " + x
        })
    };
    return View(model);
}
```

in your view you should be able to display the dropdownlist:

```
@model MyViewModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    x => x.Level,
    new SelectList(Model.Notes, "Description", "Description"),
    new { style = "display: inline;" }
)
```